# Print Text File to Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text File named "amk.txt" which looks inside like:

```
Test Number 1234

sampleCounter 123

Time                       Speed[km\h]



1                             12

2                             13

3                             14

4                             15
```

I need to print the content to Excel Sheet by using VBA. I have a Function to read the content of the file and to save the content into an Array. The Array looks inside like this:

```
TestNumber1234

sampleCounter123

TimeSpeed[km\h]



112

213

314

415
```

My Problem is, that the array which saves the fileContent does not look like the inside of txt file. 
So I have to questions:

1. makes it sense to save the file content to a array or to print it directly into the excel sheet?
2. If I want to save it into the array, why does the array not look like the text file?

I wrote two different Functions to save the file content into a array

First Function:

```
Public Function read_file_with_FSO(fileName)
Const ForReading=1
Set fileObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file= fileObject.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForReading)
fileContentFSO=Split(f.readAll,vbNewline)
read_file_with_FSO=fileContentFSO
End Function
```

Second Function:

```
Public Function read_file(fileName)
index=0
Open fileName For Input as #1
Line Input #1, textline
fileContent(index)=textline
index=index+1
Loop
Close #1

read_file=fileContent
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code to load the file to excel:

```
Sub Load_text_file()

Dim strFilename As String, strLine As String, strSprt As String
Dim lngRows As Long

strFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text files, *.txt") ' you may replace this with direct path to your file. NOTE there is no handler for "Cancel" button here - so there will be an error if you press it

Open strFilename For Input As #1

lngRows = 1

Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strLine
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRows, 1) = strLine ' !!! replace an ActiveSheet with your sheet's name

    lngRows = lngRows + 1
Loop

Close #1

End Sub
```

Then go to Excel, select the copied data, go to Data tab, press the Text to Columns button. On the first step select "Delimited" and press next. On the second step - try selecting different delimiters, unless you see that Excel splits text to columns using one of them:
[image: Delimited data]

If you find delimiter in you file (usually it is the Tab, Comma or Semicolon) then you can add following code to the sub above:

```
With ActiveSheet ' !!! replace an ActiveSheet with your sheet's name
    range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngRows - 1, 1)).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), Tab:=True ' In my case the delimiter is Tab, so set it to true, when you start typing editor will suggest parameters. If you'd like to use other character - you will need to set also that char:  other:=True, otherchar:="|"
End With
```

If this doesn't help - you may need to change your text file format or create some sub or function to get your text formatted properly in Excel.

Try the code, read comments, ask if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The array you have is each line in the file.

Since it's a text file with tabs you may be able to read & paste the contents all in to cell A1 and because of the tabs it will fill out across multiple lines and tab delimited columns.

```
Range("A1").Select 
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Or

```
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

You can google how to use the VBA clipboard, to save what's already in the clipboard, set the file contents to clipboard, then do the paste command above and finally restore whatever the user previously had in their clipboard.

The 2nd screenshot looks like the VBEditor Watch window and that's showing each line as an array item. You could iterate through the array, using `Split` to get elements and in a nested loop lay them out.